# Python 3 : why my "and" functions as "or" in "if" conditions

Tags: python-3.x, logic, boolean-logic

I'm writing a function to get coordinates of neighbours of a certain cell in orthogonal coordinates based on coordinates of the selected cell. My code is:

```
def get_neighbours_coordinates (x, y):
    neighbours = []
    for temp_x in [x-1, x, x+1]:
        # condition to drop the case, when cell has the same coordinates as treated
        for temp_y in [y-1, y, y+1]:
            if (temp_x != x) and (temp_y != y):
                neighbours.append((temp_x, temp_y))
    print (neighbours)
```

Then, if I'm calling it as (for a sake of example):

```
for i in range (10):
    get_neighbours_coordinates(i, i)
```

It returns:

```
[(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
[(1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 1), (3, 3)]
[(2, 2), (2, 4), (4, 2), (4, 4)]
[(3, 3), (3, 5), (5, 3), (5, 5)]
[(4, 4), (4, 6), (6, 4), (6, 6)]
[(5, 5), (5, 7), (7, 5), (7, 7)]
[(6, 6), (6, 8), (8, 6), (8, 8)]
[(7, 7), (7, 9), (9, 7), (9, 9)]
[(8, 8), (8, 10), (10, 8), (10, 10)]
```

While it supposed to return:

```
[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
[(3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 5), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)]
[(4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 4), (5, 6), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
[(5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 5), (6, 7), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7)]
[(6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 6), (7, 8), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8)]
[(7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 7), (8, 9), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9)]
[(8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 10), (9, 8), (9, 10), (10, 8), (10, 9), (10, 10)]
```

It looks like `and` dropped all cases where at least one of the conditions is true, while it has to drop only case where both conditions are true.

What is wrong with my code?

P.S. If I replace `and` with `or`, the code returns the desired output.
Using Python 3.9 on Windows 10.

Comment: I assume `neigbouts` is a typo.

Comment: @B.Morris Surely

Comment: `and` means it's only including the elements where both conditions are `True`.

Comment: To make it easier for yourself to to understand. Apply the logic individually to each case you expected to be there but wasn't. For example, arguments of `0, 0`. You expect it to include `-1, 0`. Your condition is saying to include it in your list if `-1` does not equal `0` AND `0` does not equal `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you are seeing are consistent with your Boolean logic. By saying `and` you are saying that you want to *exclude* both the entire row and column of the cell in question. The only cell you really want to exclude is the query cell itself.

That is, you want:

```
not (temp_x == x and temp_y == y)
```

which is the same as:

```
(temp_x != x) or (temp_y != y)
```

This logical equivalence is one of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: I can understand, why `not (temp_x == x and temp_y == y)` is what I need. But, can you explain why it is the same? As I understand, code `if (temp_x != x) or (temp_y != y)` should exactly drop central line and column